# Authenticating Routes in Feathers.js

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

I have built an app with [Feathers.js](http://feathersjs.com/). My site has routes defined like this:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.render('views/login.html', {});            
});    

app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.render('views/about.html', {});            
});    

app.get('/contact', function(req, res) {
  res.render('views/contact.html', {});            
});    

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('views/index.html', {});            
});
```

I need these four routes to be accessible to unauthenticated users. However, I also have the following routes:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  res.render('views/dashboard/index.html', {});            
});    

app.get('/dashboard/report', function(req, res) {
  res.render('views/dashboard/report.html', {});            
});    

app.get('/registered', function(req, res) {
  res.render('views/registered.html', {});            
});
```

These three routes require that a user be authenticated with *my* site via Google Auth. My question is, how do I allow anonymous users on some views in my site, but require authentication in others? I just don't see it anywhere in the [authentication docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/authentication/readme.html). It seems like it's all or none. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources/Services are not locked down by default. For the `/dashboard` routes that should be locked down, you'll need to add the authorization `before` hooks.

```
const auth = require('feathers-authentication').hooks;

exports.before = {
  all: [    
    auth.verifyToken(),
    auth.populateUser(),
    auth.restrictToAuthenticated()
  ],
  find: [],
  get: [],
  create: [],
  update: [],
  patch: [],
  remove: []
};
```

See: https://docs.feathersjs.com/getting-started/user-management.html for an example app

I'd recommend reading their page on [Authorization](https://docs.feathersjs.com/authorization/readme.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at authentication, but what you're asking about is *authorization*.  The [Feathers docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/authorization/readme.html) on it seem to indicate that they secure based on service.

If that doesn't work for you, you can still use Express middleware to secure specific routes.